# Difference between Google static map api with key and without key?

Tags: google-maps

Google static maps can be created without an api key. So what is the difference between using static map with key and without key? if we use without key then does it have any limit?

Answer (score 1):

As of June 2018, the api does not work without a key:

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that **if you use a key**

==> your quota limits will be per key otherwise per IP address

==> you can track your usage in Google Developers Console

==> you can enable billing for additional usage

Quoting from Google

> All Google Static Maps API applications require authentication using an API key. Including a key in your request allows you to monitor your application's API usage in the Google Developers Console; enables per-key instead of per-IP-address quota limits; and ensures that Google can contact you about your application if necessary.

For more information look at the link below

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/get-api-key

Comment: Actually, as per documentation, quota limits aren't based on IP address when not using an API Key, but they consume a global shared quota. Yet, to enable billing you need to sign your URLs beyond supplying your API Key. If you're using python take a look at https://github.com/allrod5/staticmaps-signature

Comment: @RodrigoMartins - can you elaborate on this?  If not using a key how are quotas tracked in an smart phone app that uses maps?  If not using IP, how are they tracking quotas?

Comment: @rolinger they do not. If you don't use a key then you are consuming their global daily quota. This is bad for business as using the global quota will make your maps stop rendering when the global quota is depleted for that day